# Retrieving database from Firebase without using ListView and set to the TexView?

Tags: android, firebase, textview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm still new to Firebase in Android and have difficulty in retrieving data from the Firebase database.

I would like to retrieve the specific database and set it to `Textview` without using the `ListView`.

For example, I want to retrieve the users name. This is the Firebase node structure:

[image: FNS]

I've been looking for the answer, but no success.

```
 mref=new Firebase("https://location-ac626.firebaseio.com");
    mref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            user val = dataSnapshot.getValue(user.class);
            Log.d("users name : ",val.getname());
            namaprofil.setText(val.getname());
        }
```

Here is my user code:

```
    public class user {
    public String name, email, kota;

    public user() {
    }

    public user(String name, String email, String kota) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.kota = kota;
    }

    public String getKota() {
        return kota ;
    }

    public void setKota(String kota) {
        this.kota = kota;
    }

    public String getname() {
        return name ;
    }

    public void setname(String name) {
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email ;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i want to retrieve the specific node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Firebase ref;
Firebase.setAndroidContext(getActivity());
ref = new Firebase(YOUR_FIREBASE_URL);
```

-------------------for single value----------

```
ref.child("universities/-KNk0.....")
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          try {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
               Map<String, Object> value = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
               namaprofil.setText(value.get("name") );
               }
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
   @Override
     public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
      }
     });
```

-----------------for multiple values--------------

```
ref.child("universities").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String s) {
                if (snapshot.getValue() != null
                        && snapshot.getKey().startsWith("-")) {

                    Map<String, Object> value = (Map<String, Object>) snapshot.getValue();
                    String Name =value.get("name").toString(); // you will get name one by one
                    Log.e("!_@@_Name-:-> ",Name);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mRef = mDatabase.getReference("universities");
mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            User val = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
            Log.d("users name : ", val.getname());
            namaprofil.setText(val.getname());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        Log.w("ERROR", "Error", error.toException());
    }
});
```

Comment: Change `addValueEventListener ` by `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`       ` by